# Default value in an asp.net mvc view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this model:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }
}
```

But based on my research and answers here, `DefaultValueAttribute` does not actually set a default value. But those answers were from 2008, Is there an attribute or a better way than using a private field to set these values to true when passed to the view?

Heres the view anyways:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Users", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.IsMale)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.IsMale)
    <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Set this in the constructor:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }

    public SearchModel()
    { 
        IsMale = true;
        IsFemale = true;
    }
}
```

Then pass it to the view in your GET action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    return new View(new SearchModel());
}
```

Comment: Will this also initialize the values to the value you set in the database as well? Or just in the object?

Comment: @Zapnologica This is written as a ViewModel, which exists independently of the data-backed model. In practice, you could create the ViewModel, and override these defaults with values pulled from a database entry (using the data-backed model), but as-is, this will always use these default values.

Now, when this gets submitted by the browser as part of a posted form, what you do with that data (whether it gets saved to the DB or whatever) is up to you.

Comment: Could this work if I overload the constructor with two parameters and set default properties just in the controller?

Comment: @Celdor I used this but overloaded the constructor with an object as parameter, set this object in the controller, worked like a charm. The values of the ViewModel where set to the values of the object I gave the constructor. (I guess using 2 parameters isn't a big difference)

Answer (score 28):

Use specific value:

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
public DateTime EntryDate {get; set;} = DateTime.Now;//by C# v6
```

Comment: It is weird that I can't use it in Asp.net core 3.1 with C# 8. It doesn't raise error, but not work either

Answer (score 17):

Create a base class for your `ViewModels` with the following constructor code which will apply the `DefaultValueAttributes`when any inheriting model is created.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    protected BaseViewModel()
    {
        // apply any DefaultValueAttribute settings to their properties
        var propertyInfos = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true);
            if (attributes.Any())
            {
                var attribute = (DefaultValueAttribute) attributes[0];
                propertyInfo.SetValue(this, attribute.Value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And inherit from this in your ViewModels:

```
public class SearchModel : BaseViewModel
{
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsFemale { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this is a clever solution, I would suggest that with C#6, it is better (more performant) to use auto-property initializers like such: `public bool IsMale { get; set; } = true`

Answer (score 4):

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password"  value="Pass@123" readonly class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

use :   value="Pass@123" for default value in  input in .net core

Answer (score 3):

In case you need to post the same model to server the solution with having default `bool` value in constructor would not be viable for you. Let's imagine that you have following model:

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public bool IsMale { get; set; }

    public SearchModel()
    { 
        IsMale = true;
    }
}
```

On view you would have something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(n => n.IsMale)
```

The problem is when user uncheck this checkbox and post it to the server - you would end up with default value set up in constructor (which in this case is true).

So in this case I would end up with just specifying default value on view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(n => n.IsMale, new { @checked = "checked" })
```

Answer (score -3):

What will you have? You'll probably end up with a default search and a search that you load from somewhere. Default search requires a default constructor, so make one like Dismissile has already suggested.

If you load the search criteria from elsewhere, then you should probably have some mapping logic.