# mvc3 default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, attributes

How can i define the default value for a model property?
The attribute `DefaultValue` is not working:

```
    [DisplayName("Infos")]
    [DefaultValue("Test")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public object infos { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DefaultValue is not used for what you think it is.

From the [DefaultValueAttribute MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

> You can create a DefaultValueAttribute with any value. A member's default value is typically its initial value. A visual designer can use the default value to reset the member's value. Code generators can use the default values also to determine whether code should be generated for the member.
>
> Note: A DefaultValueAttribute will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

Why not just set the defaults in a constructor for your Model?

```
public class MyModel {
    public MyModel() { infos = "Test"; }

    [DisplayName("Infos")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public ojbect infos { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

Since you seem to be using EF models and you want to set a default value.  You just create a partial class with a constructor.

```
public partial class MyEntity {
    public MyEntity() { infos = "Test"; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm working with EF and Database First. How can i do this from a partial class?

Comment: @MatthiasEngeler - EF has nothign to do with your view models.  You should not be passing your database model to MVC.

Comment: @MatthiasEngeler - because your data model is different from your view model.  Your views model *might* have the same requirements as your data model, in very simple models, but more often than not this is not the case.  For example, your data model might allow a null value for a given field, but your business rules dictate that it must have a value.  Or, vice versa.  Your data model might require a field to be non-null, but any given view might only work with a subset of data, and would need to make certain fields null for that view.  I've updated my answre to address your EF problem.

Comment: do you know an example project or tutorial which works with this technique? It looks time-consuming writing the models again, add the binding and so on.

Comment: @MatthiasEngeler - good software development is time consuming.  Taking shortcuts allows you to go faster, at the cost of maintainability and security.  If you want to write good code, you have to have discipline to follow accepted practices and resist taking shortcuts.  Here's one example http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/02/01/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications.aspx

Comment: Similar answer was given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637022/default-value-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view-model