# MVC how to set values metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am doing testing of a form, it has many fields.  I want to set the value of the fields so I do not have to keep re-entering it.  Is there a way to set it in the class metadata area, where I also set it as Required type.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(myMetaData))]
public partial class myClass
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Zip")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637022/default-value-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view-model

Answer (score 1):

Use **[DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)** attribute for this.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "City")]
[DefaultValue("London")]
public string City { get; set; }
```

This will resolve your concern.

Comment: What if I have validation for this field, will the validation skip this form field, when I submit the formw without a value in the textbox, using DefaultValue("Longdon")?