# How to send array of custom object as a multiform data content to asp.net web api via postman?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, multipartform-data

How to properly send array of custom objects to asp.net web api via Postman? What I have done is:

**Custom class:**

```
public class SystemConsumerConfiguration
    {
        public int SystemId { get; }
        public Uri CallbackUrl { get; }

        public SystemConsumerConfiguration()
        {
        }

        public SystemConsumerConfiguration(int systemId, Uri callbackUrl)
        {
            SystemId = systemId;
            CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
        }
   }
```

**View model in REST API:**

```
public class PostDigitalPostSubscriptionConfiguration
    {
        public IReadOnlyList<SystemConsumerConfiguration> SystemsModel { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Certificate { get; set; }


        public PostDigitalPostSubscriptionConfiguration()
        {
        }
    }
```

**And now, I make a request in Postman**

[image: Postman request]

The problem is, that model is bound with default values:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to have public setters in `SystemConsumerConfiguration`.

Should be like this:

```
public class SystemConsumerConfiguration
    {
        public int SystemId { get; set; }
        public Uri CallbackUrl { get; set; }

        public SystemConsumerConfiguration()
        {
        }

        public SystemConsumerConfiguration(int systemId, Uri callbackUrl)
        {
            SystemId = systemId;
            CallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
        }
   }
```

Answered in:
[Default value in an asp.net mvc view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637022/default-value-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view-model)